# Allocated memory for structure and passed it as pointer argument to function to fill up, but after program leaves function memory is lost

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am little bit familiar to C but I have still much to learn and I have a little problem now. I am trying read some specific Variables (specific text) from txt file and store it in structure for which I allocated memory and then work with the data I obtained and saved in allocated structure and change variables values during runtime to get correct answer.

So far, I have done first part.. to allocate and read variables from file and then if necessary dynamically reallocate existing memory for every variable for which current memory (before reallocation) is small to be saved in it.

I declared structure `varData`, instantiated 2 times and allocated memory for one of them in MAIN func:

```
varData *dynamicData;
       dynamicData = (varData*)malloc(sizeof(varData));
varData *tmp;
       tmp = NULL;
```

Then, I have created a function `loadVariablesToMemory` in which I am reading file and identifiing variables in text and reallocating memory (for which current memory is not sufficient) for additional variables  to be stored.

I run a debug and everything works fine when I am inside the function `loadVariablesToMemory`. Memory `dynamicData` is filled with variable names, but as soon as program leaves the function, memory is LOST or garbage is in it and I dont know why? As soon program jumps out from function all data in memory is LOST and garbage is in it.

```
typedef struct data {
    char varName[10];
    int  value;
} varData;

#include "functions.h"

int main()
{

    //ALLOCATING MEMORY
    varData *dynamicData;// = malloc(sizeof(varData));
        dynamicData = (varData*)malloc(sizeof(varData));
    varData *tmp;// = NULL;
        tmp = NULL;
        //tmp = (varData*)realloc(dynamicData, sizeof(varData));


    int numOfVars = loadVariablesToMemory("u02v1_input_03.txt", "r", dynamicData, tmp);

    printf("%i \n", numOfVars);
    for (int k = 0; k<=numOfVars-1; k++) {
      printf("%s \n", (dynamicData+k)->varName);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Function `loadVariablesToMemory` looks like this:

```
int loadVariablesToMemory(const char* fileName, const char* fileAccessMode, varData *dynamicData, varData *tmp) {


    FILE *fSource = fopen(fileName, fileAccessMode);

    char oneChar = '\0';
    char buffer[10];
        memset(buffer,'\0',10); //inicialization of buffer chars to \0

    int i = 0;
    int varOrNum = 0;
    int numOfVars = 0;

    bool match = false;

    while (!feof(fSource)) {
        oneChar = fgetc(fSource);           //Load letter in file
            if((oneChar == ' ') | (oneChar == '\n')) {
                i = 0;
                if((strcmp(buffer,"NOT") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"AND") == 0)  || (strcmp(buffer,"OR") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"LSHIFT") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"RSHIFT") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"->") == 0)) {
                    memset(buffer,'\0',10);
                }
                else{
                    varOrNum = atoi(buffer);    //returns (0) if varOrNum is variable (0)
                    if((varOrNum == 0) & (buffer[0] != '0'))
                    {                           //if varOrNum is a variable (0)

                        for(int j = 0; j<=numOfVars; j++) {     //control in memory for match of variable name
                            if(strcmp((dynamicData+j-1)->varName, buffer) == 0){
                                memset(buffer,'\0',10);
                                match = true;           //match found
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                                match = false;          //no match found
                        } //endForCycle

                       if(match == false){          //no match found
                            numOfVars++;            //number of variables for allocation
                            tmp = (varData*)realloc(dynamicData, numOfVars * sizeof(varData));
                            if(!tmp) {              //or equal to NULL
                                //printf("Could not resize/reallocate memory %i times \n", numOfVars);
                            }
                            else{
                                dynamicData = tmp;
                                //printf("Reallocated memory %i times \n", numOfVars);
                                strcpy((dynamicData+numOfVars-1)->varName, buffer);
                                printf("%s \n", (dynamicData+numOfVars-1)->varName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    varOrNum = 0;               //if varOrNum is a number (1)
                    memset(buffer,'\0',10);
                }
            }
            else{
                buffer[i] = oneChar;
                i++;
            }
    } //endWhileCycle (!feof(fSource))

fclose (fSource);
return  numOfVars;
}
```

Inside condition `if(match == false)` I am reallocating memory through pointer and copying to newly allocated part a "string" from buffer after that I am printing it out to console. Everything works fine until program leaves the function and return value I lost my data from memory.

Can anybody help me here how to use these pointers in argument to obtain values from function and not loose it after function is over? Because right now it doesnt give me any sense why data in memory are lost as I am returning them through pointer.

If I rewrite this funtion to only basic code in MAIN it works.

Thank you very much for any help. I am totally desperate.

Comment: @xing is right, moreover, the tmp argument is useless, you could just declare it when using `realloc()`

Comment: but How should I now access an allocated structure members? 

So far I have been accessing them by this: 

`strcpy((dynamicData+numOfVars-1)->varName, buffer);`

But now when `dynamicData` in argument is pointer to pointer I am not sure how to access the structure members in particular address.

`strcpy((*dynamicData+numOfVars-1)->varName, buffer);`

Doesnt seem to do the work now. I am totally new to this pointer - to - pointer stuff. Damn